# Symmetric 4 Body Problem but with Charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, energy, kinematics, momentum

Suppose there are 4 positive charges A(q1,m1) B(q2,m2) C(q1,m1) D (q2,m2), that are placed on the vertices of a square ABCD of side a.
Now all the charges are allowed to fly off, find the final velocities of all charges.

[image]

I tried conserving momentum along every possible direction, but the damn arrangement is so symmetric it gets us nowhere because momentum is conserved regardless of the velocities they get in combination with energy conservation. It can be seen that both red charges will get the same velocity and so will both blue charges, and realistically this should have a unique solution, but I can't get anywhere.

Solving in a general coordinate system leads to the most pathetic differential equation which is tightly coupled in two variables r1 and r2 (distances of red and blue charges from origin). I have banged my head on this problem for a while now and I don't even know if it is solvable at all. It doesn't seem that intimidating of a 4 body problem due to the symmetry.

Comment: Maybe you should consider applying conservation of energy instead of using differential equations.

Comment: @Vincent Thacker,  doesn't work, potential energy doesn't divide equally at all, no visualizable symmetry at all. I am coming to think this is an unsolvable problem by means known to a high school kid.

Comment: All this is not homework, it's not even a textbook problem, whenever I post questions here they get mistreated as homework problems, why is that. Why don't you guys entertain genuine queries?

Comment: It is certainly solvable by applying conservation of energy together with conservation of momentum. Since the charges move off at 45-degree angles by symmetry, you essentially have two unknowns which are the final velocities of the red and blue charges respectively. Conservation of energy constrains the possible solutions to an circle while conservation of momentum constrains the possible solutions to a straight line, on the Cartesian plane with the velocities as the coordinates. So it's just a matter of finding the points of intersection of the circle and line.

Comment: This is in fact isomorphic to the much simpler problem of finding the final velocities of two point charges held stationary and then released.

Comment: Whether a question was actually homework or in a textbook is irrelevant here. We prefer conceptual questions. This question is the type that you would expect to be an exercise.

Comment: @VincentThacker I see. Also, conservation of momentum isn't giving me a valid equation of a line, every direction I apply conservation of momentum gives me 0=0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134907/discussion-between-anmoldeep-and-vincent-thacker).